# ...attributes in react-native function component

Tags: javascript, react-native, spread-syntax

I have the following function component in a react-native app. In second line of code, there is `...attributes` which is confusing. While I understand that it represents spread syntax in newer JavaScript version, but I cannot find what does `attributes` mean.  If it said `..props` then that is understandable. I tried to google but couldn't find any suitable answer.

**Question**

What does `attrributes` denote in second line of code snippet below?

```
  const Loader = (props) => {
  const { loading, loaderColor, loaderText, ...attributes } = props;

  return (
    <Modal
      transparent={true}
      animationType={'none'}
      visible={loading}
      onRequestClose={() => {
        console.log('close modal');
      }}>
      <View style={styles.modalBackground}>
        <View style={styles.activityIndicatorWrapper}>
          <ActivityIndicator
            animating={loading}
            color={loaderColor? loaderColor : '#0000ff'}
            size={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'large' : 75}
          />
          {loaderText ? (
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              <Text style={styles.modalText}>{loaderText}</Text>
            </View>
          ) : (
            ''
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where is the code from??

Comment: This is a component that I see in a react native app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attributes` is the name of the newly created constant containing the rest properties from `props`.

```js
const {
  a,
  b,
  ...objectContainingEveryOtherPropertyExceptAB
} = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};
console.log(objectContainingEveryOtherPropertyExceptAB);
```

So if you use your component like this `<Loader loading foo="bar" />` then `attributes` will be equal to `{ foo: 'bar' }`

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. So `..attributes` would mean that attributes constant would contain everything except  following properties: loading, loaderColor, loaderText. Cool construct. Coming back to the component in ocd snippet, I think `...attributes` is not really needed in above code since its not being used in the Loader component. It would have been sufficient to use object destructuring to set loading, loaderColor, loaderText using this line of code: `{loading, loaderColor, loaderText} = props;`

Comment: One question related to your example  of `<Loader loading foo="bar" />`  where the loading property is not set. Is it automatically being set to undefined or null?